# will libvirt don't create vnetX tun device?

Tags: kvm, virtualization, libvirt

When I create the vm instance using libvirt, it will create a TUN device named vnetX.
I wonder would libvirt don't create the vnet device, instead, I use other method to create it.

Comment: "libvirt [...] will create a TUN device" vs. "libvirt don't create the vnet device". Doesn't make much sense to me. You should rephrase your question.

Comment: I just want to know would libvirt don't create the vnet device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES.

According to [Overriding the target element](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsNICSTargetOverride), one can override the device's name unless beginning with the 'vnet' or 'vif' which is reserved by libvirt. For example, I use TUNCTL to create the device with the name "vxnet6", and I claim this in the XML file with the 'target' parameter.

```
<devices>
...
    <interface type='ethernet'>
        <target dev='vxnet6'/>
        <mac address='aa:bb:cc:cc:bb:aa'/>
        <script path='/etc/qemu-ifup'/>
    </interface>
...
</devices>
```

Then libvirt won't create the 'vnetX' device itself any more.